# is there an algorithm to solve current rating with now one?

Tags: algorithm, rating, ratingbar

I have a old rating from the db and a new Rating from the user,
i tried to search for "rating algorithm" but they save the ratings per user. In my case i don't save the previous ratings. My rating bar is up to max of 5

currently my solution is  oldR + newR/ 2. does this make sense?

Answer (score 0):

Not really. When you think about it, such a formula would mean that newer votes are weighted much more than old ones. Imagine a sequence of votes like this:

```
Vote:     1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  5 
Rating:   1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  3
```

Clearly the rating should not be 3 in this case, it should still be 1 (or at worst 2), but with your formula it will be.

At the very least you should store the number of votes as well as the average rating, allowing you to calculate `newR = ((oldR*votesCast)+newVote)/(votesCast+1)`. This also requires to store the rating with a higher precision, not just as an integer. (You can round it off when you display it but internally you should keep track of fractions too.)

A slightly better solution is to separately store how many votes have been cast for the 5 different ratings so far, allowing you to calculate different kinds of means (geometric for example).

And obviously the most flexible (but most storage and computation intensive) is to store each individual vote with user id and timestamp, allowing you to use any algorithm you can think of.